# What is Eigen transformation of expression and their operations

Tags: eigen

I have been reading Eigen doc and some articles on internet for Eigen. I found the term "Eigen transformation of expression". I don't understand what it means. I found space transformation in geometry module in the doc but I think space and expression transformations are not similar.

It would be nice if someone could point out what is transformation of expressions in terms of Eigen. Which kind of transformations they perform, whether they have some sort of explicit list of transformations or they are hardcoded in the classes representing operands/operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what are you referring to as "Eigen transformation of expression" is the **Eigen Expression Template**.

> Expression-templates-based libraries can avoid evaluating sub-expressions into temporaries, which in many cases results in large speed improvements. This is called lazy evaluation as an expression is getting evaluated as late as possible, instead of immediately. However, most other expression-templates-based libraries always choose lazy evaluation. There are two problems with that: first, lazy evaluation is not always a good choice for performance; second, lazy evaluation can be very dangerous, for example with matrix products: doing matrix = matrix*matrix gives a wrong result if the matrix product is lazy-evaluated, because of the way matrix product works.
>
> see more on [Eigen Lazy Evaluation and Aliasing](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html)  page.

This a a simple way of abstracting the expression (as *, dot...) from the actual calculation among some other staffing. You can read more about in this paper :

- [A New Vectorization Technique for Expression Templates in C++](http://www.ajuronline.org/uploads/Volume%2010/Issue%204/104B-ProgschArt.pdf)

and it looks not documented at all in [Eigen Expression Template page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicEigenExpressionTemplates.html).